# Is there a way to get give one variable to a function and retrieve a different variable back from the second function and use it in the first function

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use the output of one function in a second function then retrieving a variable from the second function to be used in the first function. The code below is a simplification of what I am trying to do

```
def function1():
    x=15
    return x
    function2(y)
    print(x+y)

def function2():
    y=x-12
    return y

function1()
```

I am not getting an actual value for y when I check by adding a print statement for x in function2. Is there a way to do this or do i need to make a 3rd function to handle this?

Comment: ``return`` immediately terminates a function; no statements after it are run. What do you expect the line ``function2(y)`` inside ``function1`` to do? What do you think is ``y`` in this case? What are you trying to do in terms of which names should refer to which values? Are you looking for ``y = function2()`` perhaps?

Comment: After you put ```return``` in your function - the processing of the function is over. Also - where do you want to take ```y``` in ```function1``` and ```x``` in ```function2```? You need to either get it from function arguments, or have it defined as ```global```. All the variables inside function are local, unless you state otherwise.

Comment: I expect funtion2(y) to return the value of y from function2 in function1. And that y is a local variable in function 2.

Comment: Please do a basic [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). If you are unfamiliar with such basic things as calling functions, answering isolated question will not be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Pass variable x to function2, and store the return value from function2 in a local variable in function 1.

```py
def function1():
    x=15
    y = function2(x)
    print(x+y)
    return x

def function2(x):
    y=x-12
    return y

function1()
```